# URL templates for AJAX in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Following the same logic of form prototypes, is there any way to create an URL template in Symfony2?

Currently when I want to create an URL template for using with AJAX, I'm just using arbitrary numbers like `99999` and then replacing them with the actual id before requesting the URL.
Ex:

```
twig:
<select data-source="{{ path('api_route', {id: 99999}) }}">

html:
<!-- inellegant and arbitrary -->
<select data-source="path/to/api/99999">

js:
$.get(
    $(element).data('source').replace('99999', $(element).val()),
    // ...
)
```

Is there a way the print something like this?

```
<!-- perfect for mustache, underscore, coffeescript... -->
<select data-source="path/to/api/{{id}}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle). You'll be able to generate urls in your javascript, for example:

```
Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });
```

Comment: Still too much overhead (you know… one more dependency, one more way things can go wrong), but thanks for the tip. I didn't know about this bundle. :)